# Upgrading to EntityframworkCore.Sqlite 2.0.0 preview-1 causes Android app crashes

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, sqlite-net

When I Upgraded my EFCore.Sqlite 1.1.2 to Ver 2.0.0 preview-1 , my app crashes before deploy.
There is no error , there is no any exception!

I want to get rid of this error :

> unauthorized access to “/system/lib/libsqlite.so”

I search a lot in Internet and majority of them said that error would get away by the next EFCore.Sqlite update.

The UPW app runs without any problem with new sqlite update package.
The problem is Android.
Is there any thing that I must do ?

```
  <package id="Autofac" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Com.Airbnb.Android.Lottie" version="2.0.0.0-beta4" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="DNTPersianUtils.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Packaging.Tools" version="1.0.0-preview1-25301-01" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.0-preview1-25301-01" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Remotion.Linq" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLite" version="3.13.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Specialized" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Data.Common" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Contracts" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Interactive.Async" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.WebSockets" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.4.0-preview1-25305-02" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Claims" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Principal" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.4" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.231" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView" version="2.3.0-pre2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps" version="1.8.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
```

After creating clean new project :

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.0.0-preview1-final" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Packaging.Tools" version="1.0.0-preview1-25301-01" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.0-preview1-25301-01" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Remotion.Linq" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Data.Common" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Interactive.Async" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.4.0-preview1-25305-02" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.4" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.231" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Could you share exactly what NuGet packages you have installed and their versions?

Comment: @bricelam I edited the answer and put the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall these packages:

- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (or update to 2.0.0-preview1-final)
- SQLite

Comment: When I updated the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite to 2.0.0-preview1-final, I got this error : 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Comment: Even when I delete these packages I got the same error

Comment: I don't think NuGet handled the upgrade well. Try reinstalling with `Update-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -Reinstall` in the package manager console.

Comment: OK.I have created completely clean project .
I have .netstandard 1.4 plc and android project. I added the Sqlite packages and app before showing anything crashes !!!!

Comment: I added the new clean packages to the question.

Comment: Can X86 build option cause this problem ? 
I added x86_64 build option in Android properties and when I run the app , I got this error in debuge mode : 
System.NotSupportedException: Stack walks are not supported on this platform.